# Dysfunctional charger in laptop

Tags: laptop, battery

The charger I'm using right now is my second one after the first got burnt but what's in common is that they at first remained fixed on the charging port while after some time they start getting loose and you can actually move them up and down the port while they're charged.

What concerns me is that while there's a red light below the charging port that shows the lap top is charging, there's no charging icon on the task bar. Is this somehow a sign that the adapter might get burned out? It should be noted that the battery percentage is increasing with time but the absence of an icon and the loosening part worry me.

Comment: You should get the charging port repaired if it is loose.

Comment: Have you checked with a Repair Shop?

Comment: Sometimes, if the charger is not connected and the laptop gets in a location with dirt, dust etc (can happen in a laptop bag) it may be that dirt gets into the charging port. You can try a toothpick and see if gently scraping it gets dirt out. If so removing the dirt will be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that you could have previously strained the socket [which you can pretty much fix using a tiny screwdriver to push the neutral contact back over a bit] DC power jacks come in two ***very*** similar sizes, 2.1 & 2.5mm.
You can force the smaller jack into the larger socket with a bit of effort, but if you put the larger jack in the smaller socket it will appear to work but could be intermittent, unless you hold it in a specific direction.

Check your computer manual & PSU supplier for the correct jack size.